# Terminology question in group action

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Given a group action of $G$ on a set $X$, and $S \subset X$, is there a name for the set $H \subset G$ such that for all $g \in H$ and $x \in S$, $g \cdot x \in S$ ? I do not require that $g \cdot x = x$, so it is not the stabilizer of $S$ (but it contains it).

Additionnally : (just checking) am I correct when I say that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the *setwise* stabiliser of $S$ in $G$.

The notation I usually see is:

$$G_\alpha = \{g\in G \mid g\cdot \alpha = \alpha\} = Stab_G(\alpha)$$

$$G_{S} = \{g \in G \mid S^g = S\} = \{g \in G \mid g\cdot\alpha \in S\; \forall\; \alpha \in S\}$$

There's also the pointwise stabiliser of the set $S$:

$$G_{(S)} = \bigcap_{\alpha \in S} Stab_G(\alpha) = \{g \in G \mid g\cdot \alpha = \alpha\; \forall \; \alpha \in S\}$$

And these are indeed all subgroups. (In fact $G_{(S)} \unlhd G_S$)

Comment: great, thanks !